# iPhone simulators with no iOS information in Xcode

Tags: xcode, simulator

Why most of the simulators do not have iOS version but their UUID I think? And is there a way to fix this? For this specific project I have set the deployment target to 8.4.

Note that simulators all work perfectly and correctly show the iOS version on the simulator.

[image: iPhone Simulator List]

Comment: File a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple. The names with annotation are available in the Xcode Devices Shift-Command-2.

Comment: When I look at Xcode Devices window, I see that there are multiple versions of a device with the same iOS version. For example there are 3 iPad 2 (8.2). That might be the reason. How do I delete simulators, directly from that screen?

Comment: To delete a simulator from the Xcode Devices window select it and press the "delete" key or option-cicl and select "delete" or click on the gear symbol and select "delete"..

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. From the Xcode Devices window, I have deleted multiples of the same phones, quit Xcode, quit simulator, and restart Xcode. All is good now. Thanks.